# Sum dynamic column range

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, sum, row

I am trying to find the last row in an Excel table. Rows in that certain column will be different every time. So I wrote this code to find last used row in that column:

```
finalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Then I find next to last row, so that I can sum the above cells:

```
finalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

Then when trying to give a formula value to that cell the debugger always stops my program with a "End of statement needed" message :

```
Range("B" & finalRow).Value = "=SUM(B2:B" & finalRow - 1 & ")"
```

Comment: Do you mean as you enter the code into VBA editor?  If so make sure you place a space between the number "1" and the "&" as you enter the code.

Comment: Why don't you loose the second line and just do: `Range("B" & CStr(finalRow + 1)).Formula = "=SUM(B2:B" & CStr(finalRow) & ")". Why do you say *that certain column* when it is obvious that you're looking for the last row in column `A` and write the formula in column `B`. If this and the previous comment don't help, try adding the rest of the code that might be relevant.